# AWS S3 Acces Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to deploy my app on S3.

On Properties I have choose the option Static Website Hosting and on my S3 permissions, I have added this bucket policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicReadAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::motoko-dev/*"
    }
]
}
```

Is there something else to change?

I cannot get the website from my phone:

https://motoko-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/login

Comment: Please edit your question to include _ALL_ details of your configuration. For example, you mentioned CloudFront in one of your comments. Also, include why you configured Static Website Hosting, yet you are attempting access via a standard S3 URL (rather than a website hosting URL).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the region in the url:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html

> s3-website dash (-) Region ‐
> http://bucket-name.s3-website-Region.amazonaws.com
>
> s3-website dot (.) Region ‐
> http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com

Comment: Mmm, I think no because Im using cloudfront for HTTPS, I think this problem could be for that reason,

Comment: If I use http, it works: http://motoko-dev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/login, but I need it with https.

Comment: S3 doesn't support HTTPS access. You can configure Cloudfront to serve your site securely. More here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html

Comment: Yes, I have configured S3 and Cloudfront.

For that reason I guess that the problem is with Cloudfront.

Comment: Is the SSL set up correctly? It might be a good idea to double check it. Your set up should either be using the default cert provided by AWS or a custom cert you created.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, everything was right, just I need to take the endpoint from Cloudfront, which is different than S3 endpoint.